# Apache Flink checkpointing

Tags: apache-flink

We are using Apache Flink, and it's good framework.
But now we have a question  - what checkpoint storage should we use?

Our demands:

- Checpoint storage should be shared for all Flink jobs.
- Secure,  we need guaranties, like SSL or smth else
- Fast

What storage you use?

For example, we think about Ceph or Hdfs.
But for Ceph i can't find any examples and success stories, except mount storage as NFS and use it as state backend like file:// .

If you use Ceph - please write about your config and pros/cons.
Or i will be graceful for any information and advices for this theme.

Thanx a lot!

Comment: have you checked this: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/ops/state/state_backends.html

Comment: What's your question really? If you need SSL you have to go with a file system backend and they're all pretty much the same from Flink's perspective.

Comment: @gcandal We don't need SSL properly, but we need some mechanism to secure our snapshots and access to it

Comment: @fluency03 yes, i saw it. But my question is - what is better way and what storages people use for checkpointing

Comment: Requests like this are better suited to the Flink user mailing list than stack overflow. But first, check the archives -- CEPH has been discussed there already.

Comment: the question is old,but trying to answer if its usefull.. you can mount a drive and secure it. But the check point type is what matters and should be selected based on you application . FileSystem or rocks db . Rcks db will be fast as it does incremental checkpoints. File system is also good. In my usecase, where i read from kafka and keep some state and publish back to kafka With Elastic as sink. Filesystem is performing better. Although we tried with rocks db, we determined it is not needed for our usecase.